# qgis spatial index nearestNeighbour returns arbitrary number of elements

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Why does `QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbour(Point, 1)` returns more than 1 element some of the time?

I specifically set it to return the closest one neighbour.

What's the problem here?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Why does QgsSpatialIndex::nearestNeighbor(point, 1) sometimes return 2 lines?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64715/why-does-qgsspatialindexnearestneighborpoint-1-sometimes-return-2-lines)