# Is the nearest neighbor in QGIS guaranteed to return the closest geometry?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I did assume that the answer was yes, but I have developed some doubts about that because I observe something which seems to contradict:

I have a `netlayer` containing road segments (LineStrings) with a corresponding spatial index `netindex`. Now I wish to find the closest segment to a given QgsPoint `pt`.

I use the `netindex.nearestNeighbor(pt,n)` to obtain the corresponding featureIds:

```
req = QgsFeatureRequest(); 
req.setFilterFids(netindex.nearestNeighbor(pt,n))
fs = [f for f in netlayer.getFeatures(req)]
closestEdgeGeoms = [f.geometry() for f in fs]
ptGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(pt)
dists = [g.distance(ptGeom) for g in closestEdgeGeoms]
```

Now let's have a look what the `dists` are for increasing `n`:

```
n=1 # -> dists=[132.57922743885197]
n=2 # -> dists=[44.65094179417814, 132.57922743885197], ups!?
n=3 # -> dists=[232.91196346783073, 44.65094179417814, 132.57922743885197]
n=4 # -> dists=[186.9821211234746, 232.91196346783073, 44.65094179417814, 132.57922743885197], again found sth closer...
...
```

That's it. Does someone have an idea how large `n` should be to guarantee to catch the closest geometry? Or is this a bug?

---

Edit: As [Steven](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/55203/steven-kay) pointed out [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/64715/55203) is related. My question is actually answered by [Håvard Tveite's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/22646/h%c3%a5vard-tveite) answer.

Comment: Which is the problem with this code? It seems that, for `n` increasing, the new item in the `dists` list is larger than the previous ones... Or, probably, I don't understand what are you asking.

Comment: No. The new items appear on the left of the list (mysteriously...). So actually, the segment at 44m. distance is found *after* the one at 132m. distance.

Comment: i think [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/64715/55203) might be related, assuming you're only asking for n=1 and sometimes getting more edges

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there! See edit. I have not enough reputation to comment Havard's answer so he notices that he answered the question... :(

Comment: @Leolo Sorry, I didn't notice it and you are right. However, I think that the link provided by @ StevenKay should answer to your issue.