# QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeigbor() unexpected result

Tags: pyqgis, proximity, spatial-index, nearest-neighbor

I have a Linestring layer for which I have build a `QgsSpatialIndex` with the following code:

```
my_linestrings_lyr_idx = QgsSpatialindex()
for f in my_linetraings_lyr.getFeatures():
    my_linestrings_lyr_idx.insertFeature(f)
```

Now I want to find the nearest neighbor for a `QgsPoint` that is definitly located on one of the linestrings layers features, code:

```
#assume pt is of type QgsPoint
fid = my_linestrings_lyr_index.nearestNeighbor(pt, 1)
r = QgsFeatureRequest(fid[0])
nearest_feat = my_linestrings_lyr.getFeatures(r).next()
```

I expect `nearest_feat` to be the feature on which `pt` lies in any case (because this is definitly the nearest neighbor to `pt`), but in some cases that I can't exactly specify, `nearest_feat` does contain other features, which *does not* contain `pt`.

Do I use the `nearestNeighbor()` method incorrectly in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I've found an answer in this post: [Why does QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor(point, 1) sometimes return 2 lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64715/why-does-qgsspatialindex-nearestneighborpoint-1-sometimes-return-2-lines)

`QgsSpatialIndex()` seems not to work on the geometries themselves, but on the bounding boxes, and though `nearestNeighbor()` neither calculates the distances to the distinct feature geometries nor returns them ordered by the distance.

Keeping this in mind, it does not play a role whether `pt` in my question above lies strictly on a certain linestring or not.

If one wants the closest line feature to a point `pt`, we have to calculate and minimize the distance on the line features geometries to `pt`, sth. like

```
# assume pt is a QgsPoint()
# assume line_layer is a QgsVectorLayer() to test
pt_geom = QgsGeometry().fromPoint(pt)
dist, feat = min([(f.geometry().distance(pt_geom), f) for f in line_layer.getFeatures()], key = lambda x:x[0])
```