# PyQGIS how to construct QgsSpatialIndex with FlagStoreFeatureGeometries flag?

Tags: pyqgis-3, spatial-index

In the PyQGIS documentation for `QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor` (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsSpatialIndex.html#qgis.core.QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor)

we see the following **(!) Warning**:

> If this `QgsSpatialIndex` object was not constructed *with the FlagStoreFeatureGeometries flag*, then the nearest neighbor test is performed based on the feature bounding boxes ONLY, so for non-point geometry features this method is not guaranteed to return the actual closest neighbors.

Neither in the cookbook (https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#using-spatial-index) nor somewhere else on the web I could find an example on the question

**How to construct a QgsSpatialIndex with the FlagStoreFeatureGeometries flag** in PyQGIS?

(related: [Why does QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor(point, 1) sometimes return 2 lines?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64715/why-does-qgsspatialindex-nearestneighborpoint-1-sometimes-return-2-lines?rq=1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem and after some research I came up with the following code:

```
flags=QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries
```

Ex:

```
rede_agua = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('rede_agua')[0]
idx_rede_agua = QgsSpatialIndex(rede_agua.getFeatures(), flags=QgsSpatialIndex.FlagStoreFeatureGeometries)
```